# Android custom fields are not showing up in Contacts

Tags: android, custom-fields

I am trying to update existing contact with custom fields of MIME type defined for my app. This gets added to Contact available in Contacts app but it's not visible there. I am not sure what I am missing, Please suggest if you find anything wrong with below code -

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_NAME);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
operationList.add(builder.build());

operationList
        .add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        "Display Name")
                .build());

builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
// builder =
// ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
        contactId);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, contact.getId());
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "Test Action");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Test Action");
operationList.add(builder.build());
```

I am using same MIME type defined in contacts.xml file which is used for SyncAdapter.

Please help...

Comment: should they be visible? or contacts app shows just fixed mimetypes?

Comment: That's what I am asking, how to show the custom mimetype events

Comment: imho you can't,  only in your own app you can do that

Comment: Maybe my answer to similar question would help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37514338/3793570

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet to modify contact:

```
 public void update()
{       
    int id = 1;
    String firstname = "Contact's first name";
    String lastname = "Last name";
    String number = "000 000 000";
    String photo_uri = "android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/default_photo";

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    // Name
    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, lastname);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, firstname);
    ops.add(builder.build());

    // Number
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"+ " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)});
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number);
    ops.add(builder.build());


    // Picture
    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(photo_uri));
        ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, image);

        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
        ops.add(builder.build());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Update
    try
    {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to show "Custom Fields" for a event action like builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, contact.getId());
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "Test Action");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Test Action"); How to show up this in contacts app?